# Python file.write within html tags

Tags: python, html

I'm just starting with Python, one of my first scripts is to be a very simple work log.
I run it, when i finish work I press enter and it puts worktime into html file that I share with guy who hire me.

Here is the code, please do not facepalm too much, these are my first steps:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.now()
startt = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
print "Counting worktime started."
confirm = raw_input("Press enter when work finished ")
finish = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = finish - start
print datetime.datetime.now()
print delta.seconds
work_time=str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=delta.seconds))
finisht=str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
note = raw_input("What were you doing? ")
line1=['<span>','Work started: <b>', startt, '</b></span><br />']
line1f=' '.join(line1)
line2=['<span>','Work ended: <b>', finisht, '</b></span><br />']
line2f=' '.join(line2)
line3=['<span>','Work duration: <b>', work_time,'</b></span><br />']
line3f=' '.join(line3)
line4=['<span>','Note: <b>', note,'</b></span><br /><br />']
line4f=' '.join(line4)
with open("/srv/www/worklog.html","a") as worklog:
    worklog.write(line1f)
    worklog.write("\n")
    worklog.write(line2f)
    worklog.write("\n")
    worklog.write(line3f)
    worklog.write("\n")
    worklog.write(line4f)
    worklog.write("\n")
    worklog.write("<span> ========================= </span><br /><br />")
    worklog.write("\n")
```

and here is the worklog.html file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="background-color: #195B83;color:#FFF;margin: 0px;">
    <style>
        span {font-size: 12px;margin-left: 5px;}
        .logo {float: right;margin-right: 10px;margin-top:5px;}
        .first-div {background-color: #FFF; color:#195B83;width:100%;}
        .sec-div {margin-left: 5px;}
    </style>
    <div class="first-div">
        <img src="logo.png" class="logo" />
        <div class="sec-div">
            <h1>simple worklog 1.0</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <span> ========================= </span><br /><br />
    <span> Work started: <b> 2014-09-11 13:40:26 </b></span> <br />
    <span> Work ended: <b> 2014-09-11 13:40:29 </b></span> <br />
    <span> Work duration: <b> 0:00:02 </b></span> <br />
    <span> Note: <b> Testing </b></span><br /><br />
    <span> ========================= </span><br /><br />
```

And it works!

My question is - how can I include

```
</body></html>
```

tags? I tried with .replace, but my experiments failed with whole file purged. Can you give me a hint on how to make this script to keep them at the end of worklog.html ?

EDIT:

Thanks to awesome hints below, I have rewritten the code and I think that now it has a lot more sense, you can find it here:

main_script (add log to csv and add data to the website): http://pastebin.com/ZbCqJ9p9

page_refresher (no worklog adding, just put the data on website): http://pastebin.com/3hi077RK

template (with bootstrap css): http://pastebin.com/xZ7VmE1U

data files format: http://pastebin.com/0KNAXuqh

and it looks like that: http://elysium.c-call.eu/sworklog/

It's surely not the highest class and has some issues, but it's a lot better than the piece of crap I came here with :)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a cleaner solution would be to slightly change your process.

Instead of logging directly to HTML file, you should consider storing your data (start time, and end time) into a CSV file (or a text file, or a SQLite database, or whatever you want).  Python as [a built-in library for working with CSV files](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Then, you can run another script that will grab the data, process it and produce a HTML page. Since you will be recreating the HTML page each time, you don't have to bother with inserting your new data at the right place in your HTML.

It's a good practice to separate data from presentation, because it makes it easier to reuse your data in various place. In this example, if you keep your data in a in a CSV file, you can also open it with a spreadsheet application and make fancy graphs and charts for your employer ;)

Comment: +1.  You'll probably find it's invaluable having a means of looking back on your work.  You'll be able to produce your own weekly/monthly reports, pull things out of archives, etc.  It'd be a great learning exercise and project.  Then you might want to look at building it as a Django or Flask project :)

Comment: i updated the main post with pastebin links, now my code is using CSV as you suggested and mako for templating as @alecxe suggested. with some templating, it really did magic :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, you're code is much easier to read now :)

Answer (score 2):

Do not reinvent the wheel by constructing `HTML` manually using string concatenation. This makes things less readable, explicit, more complicated, difficult to maintain, error-prone. There are specialized tools, that would make it so much easier and pleasant.

Consider using a template engine,  like [`jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) or [`mako`](http://www.makotemplates.org/).

Basically, you would create an HTML template with placeholders, which would be filled with data while rendering.

Example using `mako` template engine.

- consider you have a template named `template.html` with the following content:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>${title}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <span>
          Work started: ${work_time}
      </span>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- this is what your rendering code may look like:

  ```
  from datetime import date
  from mako.template import Template


  template = Template(filename='template.html')

  title = 'Test page'
  work_time = date.today()
  print template.render(title=title, work_time=work_time)
  ```

It prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span>
        Work started: 2014-09-11
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Or, alternatively, you can construct the HTML tag by tag inside the Python code.

Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup()
html = soup.new_tag(name='html')
body = soup.new_tag(name='body')

span = soup.new_tag(name="span")
span.append(soup.new_string('Work started:'))

body.append(span)
html.append(body)
soup.append(html)

print soup.prettify()
```

Prints:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <span>
   Work started:
  </span>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user2902282 thanks, just thought real code would be more helpful in this case than theoretical advices.

Comment: i was just looking for hints and I surely got a nice one from you, that's how i learn. i used mako in my code (updated the main post with pastebin links), works pretty awesome.